# оптимизация запросов в базу в GridView::widget

Tags: yii2

В GridView::widget  я использую 2 связанных таблицы и поэтому в 4-х столбцах мне надо прописать значение запроса к смежной таблице в БД в переменную:

```
$last_event = User::getLastEvent($model->id);
```

Дальше в `'value' => function($model) {...}` этого столбца я использую `$last_event` вместо запроса. Но всё равно в итоге я получаю четыре дубля этого запроса при загрузке страницы, т.к. он используется в четырёх столбцах.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то в настройках таблицы или ещё где-то ОДИН раз задать `$last_event = User::getLastEvent($model->id);`и использовать `$last_event` по всем столбцам?

Answer (score 0):

Можно локально кэшировать результаты в свойство, если необходимо обращаться к ним несколько раз. Например такой вариант:

```
public function getUserHash($id)
{
    if(empty($this->userHash[$id])) {
        $this->userHash[$id] = uniqid();
    }

    return $this->userHash[$id];
}
```